# Domain name service transferring from Wix

Tags: nameserver, domain-registrar

I'm transferring my domain registrar from Wix to AWS Route 53 since I'm going to host everything on AWS anyway.  All instructions to decrease downtime on my website says to change the NS records on your current registrar (Wix in this case) to AWS NS to limit amount of downtime.

Unfortunately in Wix, you cannot change the NS.  Does this mean that anyone transferring their domain registrar away from Wix will have downtime no matter what?  Or is there a different approach that can be taken?

Comment: Wix is not a registrar. You need to go to the registrar to change nameservers. Go to https://lookup.icann.org/ and find out who the registrar is (if it is a gTLD, otherwise go to relevant registries). Install the zone on the new nameservers (as an exact copy of current one), double check it resolves fully, then change the nameservers at any time, and you will have exactly 0 downtime. After some time (related to TTLs) you will be free to change content of the zone without downtime.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes more sense why Wix doesn't allow NS changes.  Because the registrar points directly to them.

Answer (score 0):

If your current registrar doesn't allow you to change the nameservers, then you'll have to just transfer the domain. If you [transfer it to Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html) and have already got the hosted zone set up, then Amazon should automatically set the new nameservers correctly as part of the transfer. But you should watch the transfer process and be prepared to set them yourself if necessary, and you'll just have to eat the possible few minutes of downtime.

Comment: There's a 7 day wait time for the transfer to complete.  Right now, Wix has already shut down the site, so now my website will be down for 6 days?  It just seems like an odd way to make switching costs as high as possible when people may want to change for other reasons?

Could I have changed my A records to my AWS site (ip address) before starting the transfer?

Comment: There's a what?!? That's utterly ridiculous. No one reputable has a "7 day waiting period" to transfer out. And yes, you should have changed your address records, and I was under the impression that you had already done so.